# ndk-build No rule to make target

Tags: android, build, android-ndk

This is my **android.mk**:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

FREETYPE_SRC_PATH :=

LOCAL_MODULE := freetype

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK \
-DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY=1

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include_all \
$(FREETYPE_SRC_PATH)include \
$(FREETYPE_SRC_PATH)src

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
$(FREETYPE_SRC_PATH)src/autofit/autofit.c \
$(FREETYPE_SRC_PATH)src/base/basepic.c \
$(FREETYPE_SRC_PATH)src/base/ftapi.c \
$(FREETYPE_SRC_PATH)src/base/ftbase.c \

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ldl -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And this is **Application.mk**:

```
APP_PLATFROM := android-20
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a x86
```

After i hit ndk-build on the terminal Android Studio, i got an error message:
`make: *** No rule to make target '/app/src/main/jni/src/base/basepic.c`

I've checked **android.mk**:

```
$(FREETYPE_SRC_PATH)src/autofit/autofit.c \
$(FREETYPE_SRC_PATH)src/base/basepic.c \
```

there is no whitespace. But still got an error.

Gradle model version=6.0.1, NDK version=21.1.6352462

I need to ndk-build without problem.. any i can do to solve this issue?

Comment: What's with those non-breaking space entities (`&nbsp;`)? Those aren't in your actual makefile, right?

Comment: thanks, @Michael. I've update my question.

Comment: Make sure that when you use `\\` for line continuation, that it's the last character on that line (i.e. there should be no trailing whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

In your android.mk file you have `FREETYPE_SRC_PATH` empty. I guess it must be assigned as `/app/src/main/jni/`.